# Base 64 Image is not being rendered in email

Tags: c#

What is wrong with my below code. I am trying to place an inline image to an email.

```
public string SendEmail(SendEmail emailDetails)
{
    var x =
        "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";

    var imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(x);
    var contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var linkedResource = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg")
    {
        ContentId = contentId,
        TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64
    };

    var msg = string.Format("<p><label> Visitor's Name: {0}</lebel></p> " +
                            "<p><label> Person to Visit: {1} </lebel> </p>" +
                            "<p><label> Department Name: {2} </lebel> </p>" +
                            "<p><label> Schedule: {3} </lebel></p>" +
                            "<div>Present this image to the security guard <br /><img src=\"cid:{4}\" /></div>",
                            emailDetails.VisitorName, emailDetails.PersonToVisit, emailDetails.DepartmentName,
                            emailDetails.Schedule, contentId);

    string result;
    try
    {
        var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg, null, "text/html");
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedResource);

        var mail = new MailMessage();
        var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("somename@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(emailDetails.EmailUsed);
        mail.Subject = "Itinerary Gate Pass";
        mail.Body = msg;
        //mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtpServer.Port = 587;
        smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("somename@sommail.com", "soemthing");
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        smtpServer.Send(mail);
        result = "Message was sent";
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        result = "Failed sending Email";
    }
    return result;
}
```

If I place a break point in the `mail.Body = msg;` and copy the value of "msg" in "plnkr", I get the formatted html with the image. Can you show me how to do it please. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to create `htmlView` as an alternate view but don't seem to attach it to the message.

Comment: How do I do it? Where do I place it?

Comment: Note: Opening tag `label` and closing with `lebel` might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach your image in order to reference it with a 'cid':

```
embedImage = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath)
mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(New MemoryStream(embedImage), imageName))
mail.Attachments(0).ContentId = contentId
```

Edit: If the only way you can "get" your image is as a Base64 string, try with this... Could work, I guess

```
embedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(x)
```

Comment: What is the imagePath? I am not saving the image in any of my directory. I am directly sending it to the email uisng Base64..

Comment: Can't you send it to the email as a local path in your server? I tried in its time to convert an image from Base64String to a viewable HTML... and no way (as @user65439 has stated), the only solution I came across was this one

Comment: It’s just a very simple qr code image. If I can, I don’t want to place it in my directory because it will be plenty.

Comment: As a workaround, you could place it in your directory, attach it and then delete it after sending the email... If not, try with the last edit

Answer (score 4):

Email clients will not display base 64 images.

You will either have to display the image by setting the src to an online image accessible over the internet

for example

```
<img src="http://someurl/someimage.jpg" />
```

or you would have to attach the image and set the `src` to

```
<img src="cid:[The name of the image you attached]" />
```

So if you say for instance added an attachment named `logo.jpg` to the email, you will do something like

```
<img src="cid:logo" />
```

One important factor you need to consider when following the second approach is that certain email clients will cache images, which might cause problems with incorrect images showing.I would suggest you make use of approach one.

If you do not want to save the file to hard drive, you will need to convert the base 64 string to a byte array which is then used to create an attachment object, for example

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(x);
```

Now you can create the attachment

```
mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(New MemoryStream(bytes),attachmentName))
```

Comment: He already posted the code that tries to use the second example you've mentioned. The question from OP is how to actually achieve it.

Comment: @m.rogalski, and I answered the question. This is not possible using a base 64 string. You will need to attach a physical file. I think my answer is very clear regarding this. But I think I understand what you are saying, he wants to know how to actually attach the base64 as a physical file attachment

Comment: Yes. That’s right. As a physical attachment or an inline image.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. You should be able to convert to a byte array like you are already doing and then create an attachment

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a pleasure