# logo not shown in sending email .net 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Question: I have created an email sending flow .In email I have to
display company logo and some other details and logo make sure this is dummy base64, I am using img src assigning base64 of image but locally it is working but when I deploy on hosting site it does not display here is the code snippet:

```
MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

MailboxAddress emailFrom = new MailboxAddress("Title", "info@testing.com");
emailMessage.From.Add(emailFrom);
MailboxAddress emailTo = new MailboxAddress(emailData.EmailToName, emailData.EmailToId);
emailMessage.To.Add(emailTo);
emailMessage.Subject = emailData.EmailSubject;

BodyBuilder emailBodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
var htmlData = @"<table style='padding-left:25px;width:100%;'><tbody><tr style='line-height:0px;'><td>" +
    "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4QqCRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAUAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAhodpAAQAAAABAAAAnAAAAMgAAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABQWRvYmUAwMDP'/>" + 
    "</td></tr></tbody></table>";

emailBodyBuilder.HtmlBody = htmlData;
emailMessage.Body = emailBodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient();
emailClient.Connect("smtp.domain.com", 465, true);  
emailClient.Authenticate("companyemail@abc.com", "password");  
emailClient.Send(emailMessage);  emailClient.Disconnect(true); 
emailClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code down to a [mcve] that we could more easily see what's going on.

Comment: @phuzi yes minized

Comment: tried this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577602/base-64-image-is-not-being-rendered-in-email  ?